# java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM Operation not permitted although AndroidManifest have permits in it

Tags: java, android, sockets

This bug is getting me crezy.
I looked in forums but none answered to this particular question.
here is my sample code on AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    .
    <uses-permission android:name="android.promission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    .
    <application
        .
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        .
```

and although I put all permits as needed and uninstalled + installed the application, it still gives me an exception

```
W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:492)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:446)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:218)
        at com.diamcom.blue.connect.send(connect.java:23)
        at com.diamcom.blue.sendToServer.sendChanges(sendToServer.java:43)
        at com.diamcom.blue.sendToServer.run(sendToServer.java:25)
```

Any idea ?

Comment: now I see that on forum     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60203194/how-to-solve-java-net-socketexception-socket-failed-eperm-operation-not-permi?rq=1[link]
someone offered that the wifi I am connected with in emulator is not allowing me to connect to the api I am calling, but no solution was offered

Comment: @DipankarBaghel

Answer (score 2):

So looking through your manifest shows your internet permission is spelt wrongly.

It is: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

not: `<uses-permission android:name="android.promission.INTERNET"/>`

This might not solve your problem, but it's one step forward to figuring out what's wrong.